# Statement regarding Taylor's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I have this statement on **Taylor's Theorem** in notes :

> Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ . Let $f\in C^{m+1}(U,\mathbb R)$.Let $x\in U$ and choose $r\gt 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq U$.Then for $y\in \mathbb R^n$ such that $\|y\|\lt r$ , there is $t\in (0,1)$ such that
>
> $$f(x+y) = f(x)+Df(y)+\frac{1}{2}D^2f(y,y)+\frac{1}{3!}D^3f(y,y,y)+...$$

Geometrically , $x+th$ means a point on the line segment joining $x$ and $x+h$ as $x+th=(1-t)x+t(x+h)$

I can't understand what the statement means..can anyone explain it to me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you know the taylor theorem in 1D? If yes, define $g(t):=f(t(y-x)+x)$ and use taylor in 1D for $g$

Comment: It might help you to read the answer here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855227/interpreting-higher-order-differentials/855312#855312

Comment: Also, your notation looks incorrect.  What can $y^k$ mean if $y$ is a vector?  Really your formula should read $f(x+y) = f(x)+Df(y)+\frac{1}{2}D^2f(y,y)+\frac{1}{3!}D^3f(y,y,y)+...$, where $D^kf$ is the $k^{th}$ derivative of $f$ viewed as a symmetric $k$ tensor field, as explained in the link I posted above.

Comment: @StevenGubkin I want to understand what it means geometrically as stated in my question..,the answer provided by you was not understandable ...please canyou explian through an easy approach

Comment: @kittuu I am afraid you will not be able to understand it, geometrically or otherwise, if the statement of the theorem is nonsense.  $y^k$ has no meaning if $y$ is a vector.

Comment: @Steven I'll make amends your notation is correct..

Comment: This is really not an easy subject:  I have designed a whole course to lead up to understanding the multivariable taylors theorem.

Comment: By modifying the question in this way, you have rendered it meaningless.  There is now no use of $t$ in the theorem at all.  I was not suggesting that you use my notation without understanding it:  I was suggesting that by understanding my notation, you might resolve your problems.