# Higher order Differentials Deriving $d^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, differential

I am familiar with the equation:

$$dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} dy$$

I am trying to find a way of deriving the meaning of $d^2z$. By definition $d^2z = d(dz)$. So my first attempt is to do something like:

$$d^2z = d(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} dy)$$

But fundementally, I am not sure what taking $d(something)$ is when it is not respect to a variable. How should I handle / think about this? I came across an explanation on a similar problem: [Interpreting higher order differentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855227/interpreting-higher-order-differentials) which went like:

Lets denote $$df = \left(dx\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + dy\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)f$$
then
$$
d^2f = \left(dx\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + dy\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\left(dx\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + dy\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)f = \left(dx\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + dy\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^2f
$$

Problem is, I am having troubles finding a way of justifying (can't seem to see this rule anywhere) the ability to "take out" the $f$. Is this actually true always? The other explanations given are either just explaining intuition, or the derivation is too advance.

Question: Is the explanation outlined valid (ie, in partial differentials can you take out the f, and if so why)

Question: Are there other ways (using chain rule, composite functions etc..) to derive the expression?

Comment: Just manipulating symbols doesn't take you too far. What to you want the expression for? There are at least two ways taking second order differentials. One in the sense of a covariant derivative, which seems to be what you are heading to, but there's also the exterior calculus perspective, in which case you always have $d^2=0$.

Comment: This is the subject of differential forms (and more abstractly, exterior algebra). I would learn about differential forms to understand what $dx$ means more concretely.